# Can I configure a server to use a user port(>1023) for NTP?

Tags: linux, networking, port, ntp

Can a linux server be configured to use a high source port(above 1023) for NTP synchronization with a Stratum 1/2 server?

Are there any disadvantages to doing this?

Comment: Why [ask the same question](http://serverfault.com/q/674147/50647) again?

Comment: Deleted the old one.

Comment: What on earth is your business need for doing this?  It can't be to avoid running `ntpd` as root, because the daemon will need privilege to adjust the system clock.

Comment: I help manage a 6500 cisco router for a small ISP. We had some issues with NTP amplification DDOS attacks so we denied port 123 from any source on the inbound of our WAN interface. I have a customer that's running openSUSE in 'client' mode, but it's using source port 123 to communicate with an NTP server. Rather than change our ACL for one user I was wondering if he can configure his devices to use a high source port.

Comment: could iptables reroute it out of a different port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a fast check, it looks like it's impossible to change,
But you can try and use iptables to redirect it through another port,
[try to see, if this link will be helpful](http://openvpn.net/archive/openvpn-users/2007-11/msg00223.html)

It depends on what are your needs

Comment: That's interesting. So iptables may be exactly what I'm looking for. I'll have to look into the man pages when I have time. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

> Can a linux server be configured to use a high source port(above 1023) for NTP synchronization

I had a quick look at the man pages for ntpd(8), ntp.conf(5), ntpdate(8) on a CentOS  6 system I have to hand and non of these makes any mention of being able to change the port that they listen on or connect to. I would not expect other distros or OSes to be any different.

I guess the answer to your question is therefore no.

Comment: This guy is using openSUSE. Could outbound NTP traffic be redirected to leave out of a higher port using iptables?